# How to use Yard to document rails enum type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, coding-style, documentation, yard

I have an ActiveRecord class similar to this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # How do I document this?
  enum status [:registering, :active, :suspended, :deleted]
end
```

`status` attribute is used to build a state machine. How do I document that line of code using yard? The documentation needs to contain explanation of `status` attribute and all it's possible states.

Answer (score 7):

Just list all options as comma separated list.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # @!attribute [rw] status
  #   @return [:registering, :active, :suspended, :deleted]
  enum status [:registering, :active, :suspended, :deleted]
end
```

If you are not sure about type definition, you may consult with [YARD Type Parser](http://yardoc.org/types.html):

Comment: Bounty awarded to you for lack of a better answer ;)

Comment: It returns string instead of symbol.

Answer (score 6):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # @attr [Enumerable<Symbol>] status
  enum status [:registering, :active, :suspended, :deleted]
end
```